# Limit input length of text that contains HTML tags

Tags: php, html, strlen

I have a php web sites in wich I can manages articles. On the Add a new article form, there is a rich-text-box (allows HTML input) that I'd like to limit the character input count. I check on the server side so using the [`strlen()`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strlen) method.

The problem is `strlen` seems to give a number that is way too big. I tried to use [`html_entity_decode()`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to get the html tags out of the string but still the string length resulting seems to be wrong.

Comment: what does 'way too big' mean? isn't the text in utf-8, using some asian characters?

Comment: How about `mb_strlen(strip_tags($_POST['txtinput']))`  Check the length after stripping tags with a multibyte compatible function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`html_entity_decode` only decodes HTML entities, it doesn't ignore HTML tags. Try:

```
strlen(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string)));
```

Or the multi-byte equivalent:

```
mb_strlen(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string)), 'auto');
```

Comment: Make that `mb_strlen()` if this is to include any multibyte chars

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, I've addressed that issue. =)

Comment: @AlixAxel: I don't think it's correct to suggest `utf8_decode` as the input encoding is unknown. If input is UTF-8 encoded, then `utf8_decode` might even drop characters, so not really well.

Comment: @hakre: It works because `utf8_decode` drops chars, otherwise `strlen($str) > mb_strlen($str)`.

Comment: @AlixAxel: You don't know if `$string` is actually UTF-8 encoded. If it's Latin-1 for example, `utf8_decode` does not make any sense. That's what I wanted to point out.

Comment: @hakre: Indeed, I didn't knew utf8_decode wasn't smart enough to avoid this erratic behaviour. I'll update my answer, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the number of characters, but you don't want to count HTML markup.

You can do that by using a HTML parser, like `DOMDocument`. You load in the document (or fragment), obtain the body tag which represents the documents content, get it's `nodeValue`, normalize the whitespace of it and then you use a UTF-8 compatible character counting function:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('test.html');
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$text = $body->nodeValue;
$text = trim(preg_replace('/\s{1,}/u', ' ', $text));
printf("Length: %d character(s).\n", mb_strlen($text, 'utf-8'));
```

Example input `test.html`:

```
<body>
    <div style='float:left'><img src='../../../../includes/ph1.jpg'></div>

    <label style='width: 476px; height: 40px; position: absolute;top:100px; left: 40px; z-index: 2; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);; background-color: transparent' >
    <font size="4">1a. Nice to meet you!</font>
    </label>
    <img src='ENG_L1_C1_P0_1.jpg' style='width: 700px; height: 540px; position: absolute;top:140px; left: 40px; z-index: 1;' />

    <script type='text/javascript'> 


    swfobject.registerObject('FlashID');
    </script>

    <input type="image" id="nextPageBtn" src="../../../../includes/ph4.gif" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 795px; ">

</body>
```

Example output:

```
Length: 58 character(s).
```

The normalized text is:

```
1a. Nice to meet you! swfobject.registerObject('FlashID');
```

Take care that this counts the text-size including things like text inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: There some related xpath use demonstrated at [this answer to *substring in html*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10210900/367456).