# substring in html

Tags: php, substring

```
<p style="color:red;font-size:12px;">This economy car is great value for money and with the added benefit of air conditioning is ideal for couples and small families. A ?500 excess applies which can be waived to NIL for only <b>5.00</b> per day</p>
```

using the below 2 methods

```
substr($mytext,0,25);
```

and

```
 $s = html_entity_decode($mytext);
 $sub = substr($s, 0, 50);�
```

need to get the first 50 chars...anybody please help

thanks

Comment: What should the final result be? (and why does this question get 3 upvotes? It's not clear what the question is about.)

Comment: Try `$sub = substr(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($mytext)), 0, 50);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is working... Just try

```
echo (substr(strip_tags($mytext), 0, 25));
```

http://www.ideone.com/6TgJX

Comment: Entities anyone? Multibyte strings anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You need a HTML Paser, locate and read out the plain text and pick the substring, here an example with `DOMXpath`:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$chars50 = $xp->evaluate('substring(normalize-space(//body),1,50)');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nYwemX):

> string(50) `"This economy car is great value for money and with"`

Take note that you'll get an UTF-8 encoded string here. You can do this on your own as well with regular expressions (which might [help you to cut at words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494901/367456)) for example:

```
# load text from HTML
$text = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html)->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->nodeValue;

# normalize HTML whitspace
$text = trim(preg_replace('/\s{1,}/u', ' ', $text));

# obtain the substring (here: UTF-8 safe operation, see as well mb_substr)
$chars50 = preg_replace('/^(.{0,50}).*$/u', '$1', $text);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FDyNBa)

If you're using `strip_tags` instead of a HTML parser, you would need to deal with the different encodings on your own. As the original string already has the question-mark which signals an unicode replacement character, I'd say you already deal with borked data so better use a library that re-presents like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) instead of `strip_tags` which is not safe (see the warning on the PHP Manual page).