# Why does PHP strip_tags("is<isvery interesting <thatthis willbe stripped") return is?

Tags: php, strip-tags

I am about to make a char counting function which counts input from a tinyMce textarea.
Server-side validation with code like this:

```
$string = "is<isvery interesting <thatthis willbe stripped";
$stripped = strip_tags($string);
$count = strlen($stripped); // This will return 2
```

You might notice that $string has no tag at all, anyway `strip_tags()` strips everything from the first less-than sign on.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: And what is the result you expected?

Comment: @MikeB: I hope 'F' means full.

Comment: This question might be of interest for you: [Limit input length of text that contains HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089062/limit-input-length-of-text-that-contains-html-tags) - you might get it to work with `DOMDocument->loadHTML`, see [my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089206/367456) for a code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been documented:

> Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or
>   broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 4):

`strip_tags` is actually quite dumb. It strips everything, that only remotely looks like an HTML tag. That is, starting with `<` and some alpha-numeric sign until the closing `>` or as far as it can get.

The observed behavior is in this context a bug. However, `strip_tags` is then not the tool to do error correction on input HTML. Its purpose is to strip away stuff, so that the remainder is safe to embed in websites. In doubt, it strips more, which is a good thing.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call it a good thing, but at the very least it's the safest option.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a dumb function, it does exactly what it was designed to do.

Comment: @PaulBain with "dumb" I'm just referring to the fact, that `strip_tags` doesn't do any fancy HTML parsing, error correction or such. It is implemented in a simple way to cater for 90% of use cases, that's all I wanted to express.